# Converting open riser staircase to closed

Tags: stairs

My staircase has open risers, and  metal riser bars between the treads.

I can only fit a few millimeters between the riser bar and the tread. Would 3mm plywood work as a riser or am I better off trying to remove the metal riser bars?

I do not have the tools to cut through the metal riser bars so I would rather leave them in if possible

I’m worried anything thin enough to fit would be too thin and likely  bend/creak

How should I best convert these to closed?

[image]

Comment: I do not know what your metal riser bars are, what function they serve etc.  A few photos of the stairs would help

Comment: Yes, I'm having trouble picturing your situation. Please provide clear photos. Also, don't cut any metal out of your stairs. That's probably a very bad idea.

Comment: **Do not  cut them**. The metal bars are what is keeping the two stringers spaced together at the appropriate distance. I.E. keeping them from moving apart.  How about two piece risers with bar sandwiched in between. Or behind the bars. Or  one riser with a dado channel routed out on the back for the bar sit in. ???

Comment: Added a photo. Are you sure? I’ve done more reading about staircase design than I care to admit and the only thing like this I can find is riser bars, which are installed to meet building regs about how big a gap can be between steps. Google stair riser bars and you find lots like this

Comment: With out the bar all stress will be born by the tread and the screws attaching them to the stringers.  The bar is structural not simply a code fix.  I like the open stairs better n part because of air circulation and lighting

Comment: Is there a structural plate or bar below the treads, that spans from stringer to stringer?

Comment: It looks like the top step or two have wood risers? Do they bend or creak? Have you investigated how those were installed and whether or not the bar is behind those?

Comment: No there aren’t any structural plates under the treads. The top wood risers are above the ceiling, which is why they’re closed presumably. Also means I don’t have access to behind them